# Error after changing android package name

Tags: android, package, manifest

I changed my package name  from (com.welldone.dgp to com.welldone.dgpDemo) in the AndroidManifest.xml and after this the package name under src folder. No errors but when I run the app I got this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.welldone.dgpDemo/com.welldone.dgp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.welldone.dgp.MainActivity

I search inside the all files (except the class ones) in my project looking for a bad path but everything is pointing to the new package name "com.welldone.dgpDemo) but if you see the error, something is pointing at the old package name. Could you help me? thanks!

Comment: Did you change the package name in MainActivity? Every class has the package defined at the top.

Comment: Post your current manifest. It's still looking for `MainActivity` in package `com.welldone.dgp`.

Comment: if you change in the manifest then be sure all classes are changed using refactor..by right clicking your project and pasting what's in the manifest..

Comment: Clean your project or restart your ide

Comment: I changed the reference in every class, but I noticed that there is a lot of references in the manifest, I changed them, now the first activity runs, but I got another error: `No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0` Before renaming everything worked fine :(